# Scope of a reference variable in an Event Handler C#

Tags: c#, button, checkbox, event-handling, scope

I have a simple form with a button control on. When clicked, a checked checkbox appears.

I'm a beginner and wanted to know what happens to my reference variable myCheckbox and what happens to the checkbox object it is pointing to on the heap when the event Handler is out of its lifetime ?

If the checkbox object on the heap exists still can I access it by pointing another reference to it ?

Thank You

Lee

My code -

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox myCheckbox = new CheckBox();
            myCheckbox.Name = "My Check Box";
            myCheckbox.Checked = true;
            myCheckbox.Location = new Point(500, 150);
            this.Controls.Add(myCheckbox);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The  object referenced by `checkBox` is maintained by the `Controls` collection, this has nothing to do with the lifetime of the event handler - in fact the event handler has no "lifetime"-  it is a normal method that happens to fire when you click a button.

`mycheckBox` on the other hand is destroyed as it is a local variable.

But yeah you can reference the `CheckBox` object later like so:

```
var checkBox = this.Controls[index] as CheckBox
```

If the `CheckBox` is removed from the collection and is no longer referenced, then it is eligible for garbage collection.